# phonegap file API not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

am trying to upload a file and some data to the server . after looking into some examples and answer to another question here at SO, have used the following javascript.

html button

```
<button onclick="SendData()">Send</button>
```

Javascript code

```
function SendData(){

// data gathering code above
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "logo";    options.fileName = imgurl.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";    options.params = data;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imgurl, encodeURI(GetWebServiceUrl()), win, fail, options);

} // Send data function

var win = function (r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

var fail = function (error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}


function IsDataValid()
{
    var valid = true;

    $(".required").each(function(){
      if($.trim($(this).val()) == '')
      {
          alert ('One of the required field seems empty: ' + $(this).prop('id'));
          valid = false;
          return false;
      }
    });
    return valid;
}

    $("#buisnessimage").click(function(){
        GetImage();
    });


function GetImage()
{
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    allowEdit : true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG});    
}

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    imgurl = imageURI;
    $("#buisnessimage").prop('src', imageURI);
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

but upon invoking, nothing happens. am testing on Genymotion emulator and compiled locally using eclipse . have cordova 2.9.0

any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors in logcat or the console? Are you using the `deviceReady()` function? In what order are you loading cordova.js and jQuery?

Comment: thank you for the answer. i tried it on genymotion emulator and it did not show any error or message .

Comment: In logcat it didn't show any error message? Can you include the code that shows how you are calling the function? Also it looks like you are missing a function definition.

Comment: i left the upper part of function as it has long parameter assignments. will update with the required code..

Comment: code updated with function name and html button